# How do I style a specific element with day and night theme?

Tags: android-studio

I have an android app that makes use of some Material Card Views.
In my `styles.xml` file, I am applying two types of styling for Material Card View;

- service.day, which shows a light background for theme.xml day.
- service.night, which shows a darker background for theme.xml night. ie battery saver.

"service", in context, just relates to the style's application in my app - a material card view which shows a single train *service*.

**The Code:**

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="service.day" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView" >
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#f4eada</item>
</style>
<style name="service.night" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView" >
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#444444</item>
</style>
```

And the following is placed in my theme files under the default "base application theme" code.

**Theme.xml**

```
<item name="materialCardViewStyle">@style/service.day</item>
```

**Theme.xml (Night)**

```
<item name="materialCardViewStyle">@style/service.night</item>
```

The above will apply that styling to *all material card views* in my app.

What I am looking for, is to keep one set of material card views as above styling, but implement a second set of card styles for a different part of the app.

Comment: You can add individual styles to each to `MaterialCardView` that you use using the `style`  XML attribute that is available with each view, is that what you were asking about?

Comment: I do want to add individual styles , that's correct, but I want the individual styles to change when the device enters battery saver mode, ie a dark theme (night). So essentially I want individual styles each with their own day/night styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment above

You can inherit as you like by using the `service.day` or `service.night` as the `parent` theme. That would mean something like make a theme say xyz, extend the properties of your theme(which in turn extends the properties of the default theme of Android) and then customise it accordingly.

Let me explain it with an example

Put something like this in the `values/themes.xml` file

```
<style name = "service.day.CustomCardTheme1" parent="service.day">
<!--Your new attributes here, Note that this will retain the property defined in the parent that is your background-->
</style>
```

And a similar night value in `values-night/themes.xml` file

```
<style name = "service.day.CustomCardTheme1" parent="service.day">
<!--Your new attributes here, Note that this will retain the property defined in the parent that is your background-->
</style>
```

You can keep creating your own `CustomCardTheme` say n any number of times with this inheritance and give it all the own colors and properties you like, just within the scope of the `Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView` style